# Getting vertices and indices from a List<Vector3>

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I am trying to achieve drawing triangles from a list of Vector3 Elements.

Previously I have used a heightmap to create vertices and indices however this worked out well because it was a rectangle in a 2d array but not a list.

How would I go about (or modify) my existing code to deal with a list instead of a 2d array.

My existing code for Vertices:

```
public VertexPositionNormalTexture[] getVerticies(float[,] heightData)
    {
        VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[terrainLength * terrainWidth];

        for (int y = 0; y < terrainLength; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth; x++)
            {

                // position the vertices so that the heightfield is centered
                // around x=0,z=0
                vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Position.X = terrainScale * (x - ((terrainWidth - 1) / 2.0f));
                vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Position.Z = terrainScale * (y - ((terrainLength - 1) / 2.0f));

                vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Position.Y = (heightData[x, y] - 1);

                vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].TextureCoordinate.X = (float)x / terrainScale;
                vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].TextureCoordinate.Y = (float)y / terrainScale;
            }
        }

        return vertices;
    }
```

Here is the code for indices:

```
public int[] getIndicies()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int [] indices = new int[(terrainWidth - 1) * (terrainLength - 1) * 6];

        for (int y = 0; y < terrainLength - 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth - 1; x++)
            {
                int lowerLeft = x + y * terrainWidth;
                int lowerRight = (x + 1) + y * terrainWidth;
                int topLeft = x + (y + 1) * terrainWidth;
                int topRight = (x + 1) + (y + 1) * terrainWidth;

                indices[counter++] = topLeft;
                indices[counter++] = lowerRight;
                indices[counter++] = lowerLeft;

                indices[counter++] = topLeft;
                indices[counter++] = topRight;
                indices[counter++] = lowerRight;
            }
        }

        return indices;
    }
```

Comment: Are you just talking about the 2 dimensional array that you're passing in w/ floats?

Comment: No thats what I had before, now I have just a list of vector3's, im wondering how to create triangles based on that list, because obviously it wouldnt be a perfect rectangle like my current code is right now

Comment: I'm sorry, i have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be looking at `List<List<float>` or whichever type you're working with here.

Syntax might change slightly.